# Sorting 4 constants with 2 if -thens

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm having troubles trying to think of a way to sort these 4 "costs". 
My end goal is to not have two identical if-then statements inside the method, this example is just a quick mockup.
I'm sure it's simple code that I'm missing.

```
int discount_InsideZone;
int discount_OutsideZone;
int insideZone;
int outsideZone;

static int something(boolean discounted, int startzone, int endzone)
{
/* if 
   discounted == true && startzone == endzone Return discount_InsideZone;
   discounted == true && startzone <> endzone Return discount_OutsideZone;
   discounted == false && startzone == endzone Return insideZone;
   discounted == false && startzone <> endzone Return outsideZone;
*/
}
```

Comment: Hi i think youve misunderstood that java == javascript.Please remove tag javascript if its not used / will be used in the post.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
static int something(boolean discounted, int startzone, int endzone)
{
    if (startzone == endzone)
        return (discounted ? discount_InsideZone : insideZone);
    return (discounted ? discount_OutsideZone : outsideZone);
}
```

Comment: I never thought to add ternary operators for this! Thanks for answering it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compare with `==`, just use them directly in the `if` statement.

```
boolean inside = startzone == endzone;

if (discounted) {
    if (inside) return a;
    else return b;
}
else {
    if(inside) return c;
    else return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since javascript is tagged here and it's only a mock, please let me mock this in javascript.

```
var discount_InsideZone;
var discount_OutsideZone;
var insideZone;
var outsideZone;

function something(discounted, startzone, endzone) {
    if (discounted) {
        return startzone === endzone ? discount_InsideZone : discount_OutsizeZone;
    }
    return startzone === endzone ? insideZone : outsideZone;
}
```

Unfortunately this is the best I could come up with at this point.

Comment: You're good, and the javascript/pseudo code is fine. I almost answered the same, then realized that flipping the `discounted` and `startzone == endzone` checks would be slightly better. ;-)